# How Android WebView access network?

Tags: android, paypal, webview

**I'm requested to upgrade PayPal by using WebView ,and  have to enable my app to open TLS V1.2 in WebView between API 16 and API 19  .                 I find that `SSLContext` can use TLS V1.2 by creating
    socket.However,it can't be used directly as
    "webview.setSSLContext()".   Then,I search lots of Android soruce code
    ,but I can't find how WebView access network like using
    httpurlconnection or socket .**

Q1:How Android WebView access network ?
  Q2:How I open TLS V1.2 in WebView?
  Q3:What widget I should replace WebView with?